# join three pandas data frames into one?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my pandas Data Frames:

```
pandas1 = pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
pandas2 = pandas.DataFrame([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90])
pandas3 = pandas.DataFrame([100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900])
```

How can I meld this there Data Frames into one,like so:

```
1,10,100
2,20,200
3,30,300
4,40,400
5,50,500
6,60,600
7,70,700
8,80,800
9,90,900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pandas1.join(pandas2, lsuffix ="2").join(pandas3, lsuffix="3")
```

the `lsuffix` is only required because all of your columns have the same default name of (`0`)

This code is actually joining the dataframes on their indexes.  See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging

EDIT:

If you are trying to join Series objects rather than Dataframes, then you want

```
pandas.concat([pandas1, pandas2, pandas3], axis=1)
```

Comment: now I have the following error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: type of my pandas Data Frame is: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: @MichaelVayvala: To make it clear, that means that the object is *NOT* a DataFrame.  Series and DataFrames are different types.

Answer (score 0):

just try this .. it should work:

```
pandas.concat([pandas1,pandas2,pandas3],axis=1)
```